# iPad simulator Interface rotation 90°

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I am developing an app (a drum machine) for the iPad, I have a draft of the user interface.
The interface is OK in iOS 6.1 simulator:

[image: The interface on iOS 6.1]

But it's turned 90° in iOS 5.1 simulator:

[image: The interface on iOS 5.1]

This is how I call the View (after some help from stackoverflow members)

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{    
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
self.viewController = [[XDrumViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"XDrumViewController" bundle:nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
 }
```

How to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely that you are not defining

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation;
```

which is required on iOS < 6 to make autorotation work (see [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation%3a)). For a quick test, define:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation);
}
```

in your view controller. This will enable autorotation for landscape only (i.e, it will force your controller to landscape).

Comment: I have set it to return NO because I don't want the interface to autorotate, I only want lanscape mode...but nothing has changed...

Comment: ok, instead return: `UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation)`; by returning NO you are preventing the UI to go into landscape orientation.

Comment: I have tried to set it to YES: it did the trick. I thought that "NO" meant "do not rotate" ;-)

Comment: your UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation) works better, but it still rotates to landscape (right home button) and landscape right. How to keep it fixed to Landscape right only ???

Comment: use: `return (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);`